# Select/copy text form TexShop Console

Tags: texshop, terminal-output

I use TexShop and would like to be able to copy text from the console of TeXShop to post it for instance in this forum. I cannot do that. One cannot select text from the console. Is there a way to copy error messages that TexShop prints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When TeXShop stops for an error, the typesetting process is still on and the Console is not accessible for copying text.

Press the `x` key and then the return key to stop compilation and the Console will allow copying for pasting.

More generally, the Console window will allow copying text when the process is finished.

Here's an example: I planted a bug in a file and TeXShop stops; in the lower box you already see the `x`

[image]

After hitting return, I get

[image]

and I can paste here the error message:

```
./surehy.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
l.14 Hei\undefinde
```

Comment: Rather than pressing x and 'enter', which runs the remaining document ignoring errors, one can also just press the 'Abort' button in the TexShop console and then copy and paste as desired.

Comment: @Wakabaloola No, `x` will stop. You're confusing with `q`, perhaps. Actually, I realize now that the hint by TeXshop is misleading.

Comment: I'm sorry but (I checked yet again just now) this is what happens in my local installation of TexShop (Version 5.21): 
x and 'enter' makes it ignore errors and produces a pdf output anyway (allowing one to copy and paste as you suggested in your answer), whereas 'Abort' stops it in its tracks, allowing one to copy and paste text (without the pdf output). (q instead enters \batchmode, I don't mean that)

Comment: @Wakabaloola Just tried with the last version of TeXShop. The document `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}a\ddt\end{document}` produces an error and upon typing `x` and hitting return, no PDF file is produced. To the contrary, one is produced if you add `\newpage` before `\ddt`, because a complete page has been shipped out at the time of the error. The text you type in the window is passed to the TeX engine and from day one `x` interrupts.